# Prove that $k \leq n.$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $V$ be a vector space and $S = \{v_1, ..., v_k\}$ be a linearly independent subset of $V$. Given that every vector in $S$ can be written as a linear combination of vectors in the set $W =\{w_1, ..., w_n\},$ prove that $k \leq n$.

Clearly, $S \subseteq \mathrm{span}(W)$.

If $S$ is a maximal linearly independent subset of $V$, then it is a basis for $V$, and so $\mathrm{span}(W) = V$. Since $S$ and $W$ are both spanning sets in this case, $n \geq k$.

If $S$ is not a maximal linearly independent subset of $V$, then we can add linearly independent vectors $v_{k+1}, ..., v_m$ so that $S$ is. However, I seem to be stuck here.

As an alternative approach, I tried to find a contradiction: if $n < k,$ then $S$ is linearly dependent, but I wasn't sure how to find this. I tried to do this using brute force, by trying to show that there exist scalars $c_1, ..., c_k,$ not all zero, such that

$c_1v_1 + \cdots + c_kv_k = 0.$ Since $v_1, ..., v_k \in\mathrm{span}(W),$ this is equivalent to saying that

$c_1(d_{1_1}w_1 + \cdots + d_{1_n}w_n) + \cdots + c_k(d_{k_1}w_1 + \cdots + d_{k_n}w_n) = 0$ for some scalars $d_{1_1}, ..., d_{1_n}, d_{2_1},...,d_{2_k},..., d_{k_1},..., d_{k_n}\in\mathbb{F}$. And then I got stuck again.

So I tried claiming that $w_{t_1} \in \mathrm{span} \{v_1,w_1, ... ,w_{t_1-1}, w_{t_1 + 1},...,w_n\},$ where $1\leq t_1 \leq n$ (this is because all of $v_1, ..., v_k$ must be nonzero and $v_1 = c_1w_1 + \cdots + c_nw_n,$ so at least one $w_{t_1}$ and $c_{t_1}$ must be nonzero, and hence $w_{t_1} = c_{t_1}^{-1}v_1 - c_{t_1}^{-1}c_1w_1 - \cdots - c_{t_1}^{-1}c_nw_n$).

> Any hints as to how I can better approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $span(S) \subseteq span(W)$. Hence, $k=\dim (span(S)) \leq \dim(span(W))\leq n$.

Comment: thanks for the answer. but how would you go about proving that  if $S \subset W,$ then $\dim S \leq \dim W$?